# Причина неправельного вывода переменной 10.12?

Tags: c, printf, точность

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("10.10 = %.15lf\n", 10.10);
printf("10.12 = %.15lf\n", 10.12);
printf("10.15 = %.15lf\n", 10.15);
return 0;
}
```

Почему при работе программы переменная 10.12 выводится неправильно? Это случается только, когда точность больше или равна 15.

Comment: Потому что число 10.12 не представимо точно типом `double`. Длинное объяснение по ссылке из предыдущего комментария.

Comment: мантисса типа double https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Число_двойной_точности имеет размер 52 бита. Значит точность десятичного представления Log10(2^52)=15.65 Значит после пятнадцати цифр будет уже белиберда.